# C# System.Drawing Reference issue

Tags: c#, reference, system.drawing

I'm a total noob when it comes to C#, C++ (C anything) and visual studio.

I'm trying to draw a table over a chart using

```
public override void OnPaintChart(PaintChartEventArgs args)
        {
            Graphics gr = args.Graphics;

            Font font = new Font("Arial", 10);
    
            for (int i = 0; i < KeyLevel.Length; i++)
                gr.DrawString(KeyLevel[i].ToString(), font, Brushes.LightGray, 20, 23 * i + 30);
        }
```

but i'm getting the following error:
**"The type 'Graphics' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc6......."**

If I right click my project and go to Add > References, the only available system.drawing is showing as version 4.0.0.0.

I've updated visual studio and updated .net.

I've stated/referenced?? (dont know terminology)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
```

at the beginning of my script.

How do i get version 6.0.0.0?

I'm really stuck with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The cool cats use Qt for drawing these days. That said, are you sure you're writing C++?

Comment: C# or C++ - which is it? It sure _looks_ C#ish.

Comment: Sorry its c# not c++

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? What SDK is installed? What type of project template did you use? ...

Comment: `using System.Drawing;` That using does not mean that the relevant assembly is automatically referenced its just a shortcut that you don't have to write the complete name of the class. So you don't have to say `System.Drawing.Graphics` but just `Graphics`.  You still need to reference the assembly. If its net 6. as you stated you need this https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/ nuget package with the relevant assemblies when the template you used for setting up the project hasn't referenced it already.

Comment: I've come across .net6. I was using visual studio 2019. Currently downloading 2022 and .net6.

Comment: I'll update this thread once installed. Think this might be the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Solution if anybody runs into same problem.

Update to Visual Studio 2022.

Update .net

In visual studio, right click project > Manage NuGet Packages

Search drawing and install package.

Swear at Microsoft for making life hard.

Done.

Comment: Yes thank you. Everywhere I looked people just said to "add the reference" but it was nowhere to be found. This actually solved the problem.